# unable to use Libxml on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, libxml2

im trying to use libxml2.2 to parse an XML file in my iPhone app but I'm having problems. i keep getting errors like "error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory". after doing some searching on here and on the internet in general i found that you need to add "/usr/include/libxml2" to the Header Search Paths. i have done this and i'm still having the same problem. anybody have any idea what is going on?

also the exact same code works just fine on a coworker's computer but not on mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `"usr/include/libxml2"` or `"/usr/include/libxml2"` (there's a forward slash at the beginning of the path)

Comment: sorry typo yes i added "/user/include/libxml2"

Comment: turns out i had accidentally added the directory recursively and that seems to of messed it up for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to add `-lxml2` to **Other Linker Flags**